# groupby a column and count items above 5 in another pandas

Tags: python, pandas, counting

So I have a df like this:

```
NAME    TRY SCORE  
Bob   1st   3  
Sue   1st   7  
Tom   1st   3  
Max   1st   8  
Jay   1st   4  
Mel   1st   7  
Bob   2nd   4  
Sue   2nd   2  
Tom   2nd   6  
Max   2nd   4  
Jay   2nd   7  
Mel   2nd   8  
Bob   3rd   3  
Sue   3rd   5  
Tom   3rd   6  
Max   3rd   3  
Jay   3rd   4  
Mel   3rd   6
```

I want to count haw mant times each person scores more than 5?
into a new df2 that looks like this:

```
NAME    COUNT  
Bob     0  
Sue     1  
Tom     2  
Mary    1  
Jay     1  
Mel     3
```

My attempts have been many - here is the latest

```
df2 = df.groupby('NAME')[['SCORE'] > 5].count().reset_index(name="count")
```

Answer (score 2):

First create boolean mask and then `aggregate` by `sum`- `True`s values are processes like `1`:

```
df2 = (df['SCORE'] > 5).groupby(df['NAME']).sum().astype(int).reset_index(name="count")
print (df2)
  NAME  count
0  Bob      0
1  Jay      1
2  Max      1
3  Mel      3
4  Sue      1
5  Tom      2
```

**Detail**:

```
print (df['SCORE'] > 5)

0     False
1      True
2     False
3      True
4     False
5      True
6     False
7     False
8      True
9     False
10     True
11     True
12    False
13    False
14     True
15    False
16    False
17     True
Name: SCORE, dtype: bool
```

Answer (score 2):

Just using `groupby` and `sum`

```
df.assign(SCORE=df.SCORE.gt(5)).groupby('NAME')['SCORE'].sum().astype(int).reset_index()
Out[524]: 
  NAME  SCORE
0  Bob      0
1  Jay      1
2  Max      1
3  Mel      3
4  Sue      1
5  Tom      2
```

Or we using `set_index` with `sum`

```
df.set_index('NAME').SCORE.gt(5).sum(level=0).astype(int)
```

Comment: I don't like this answer. Using the dot notation to access the column `SCORE` is not idiomatic and will only work with strings without spaces. I also don't like the use of `assign` which only complicates matters for new users.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to write a custom groupby function where you take the scores of each group and sum up those that are greater than 5 like this:

```
df.groupby('NAME')['SCORE'].agg(lambda x: (x > 5).sum())


NAME
Bob    0
Jay    1
Max    1
Mel    3
Sue    1
Tom    2
Name: SCORE, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want counts as a dictionary, you can use `collections.Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter

c = Counter(df.loc[df['SCORE'] > 5, 'NAME'])
```

For a dataframe you can map counts from unique names:

```
res = pd.DataFrame({'NAME': df['NAME'].unique(), 'COUNT': 0})

res['COUNT'] = res['NAME'].map(c).fillna(0).astype(int)

print(res)

   COUNT NAME
0      0  Bob
1      1  Sue
2      2  Tom
3      1  Max
4      1  Jay
5      3  Mel
```

Answer (score 0):

Filter dataframe first, then groupby with aggregation and reindex to fill missing values.

```
df[df['SCORE'] > 5].groupby('NAME')['SCORE'].size()\
                   .reindex(df['NAME'].unique(), fill_value=0)
```

Output:

```
NAME
Bob    0
Sue    1
Tom    2
Max    1
Jay    1
Mel    3
Name: SCORE, dtype: int64
```